# BDC Paging

Tags: sharepoint, paging, bdc

I’m using SharePoint (Business Data List web part) with the BDC. I use this to bring back data from the database, nice and simple.

However, when I do a search I receive a number of results being paged by the web page. This takes a while to bring back any search results (even when navigating between the paged data). I’m guessing (please forgive my ignorance) that all the results are returned and the paging is done on the SharePoint server, not at the SQL level. Can we do SQL paging for example [SQL Paging](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/01/434314.aspx)

Please can someone shed some light on this?

Kind regards
Bones

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is brings back ALL the data. That's really not how I saw it working. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/enterprisesearch/archive/2008/05/22/understanding-total-hits-paging-in-the-moss-2007-search-api.aspx) and [here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-people-search-lessons-learned-covering-basics/).

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery paging with list view web `part.List` view web part is used for populating data from sharepoint content database